# showing select on check reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, state

I am trying to get a select to show/hide on check but the select just renders and does not disappear nor reappear. I am fairly new to react, so I am sure I am doing something wrong.

```js
export default class TreeTest extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      checked: [
        '/grantSettingsPermissions/Admin',
        '/grantSettingsPermissions/ContentGroups/AddLocations', 
      ],
      expanded: [
        '/grantSettingsPermissions',
        '/grantSettingsPermissions/ContentGroups',
      ],
    };

    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
    this.onExpand = this.onExpand.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onCheck(checked) {
    console.log(checked);
    this.setState({
      checked,
    });
  }

  onExpand(expanded) {
    this.setState({
      expanded,
    });
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { checked, expanded } = this.state;
    const content = this.state.checked
    ? <select>
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
      : null;
    return (
            <div>
              { content }
              <CheckboxTree
                  checked={checked}
                  expanded={expanded}
                  nodes={nodes}
                  onCheck={this.onCheck}
                  onExpand={this.onExpand}
                  expandDisabled={true}
                  onChange={ this.handleChange }
              />
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a feeling I just need to add stuff to the onCheck function, but I am not entirely sure. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should be:

```
const content = this.state.checked.length === 0
  ? <select>
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select>
  : null;
```

Comment: Oh nice, that is working. It is working when all the boxes are unchecked. is there a way to check for each individual box? so when one is checked/unchecked a select is shown/hidden?

Comment: It's difficult to say, show me your nodes structure. I'll check a bit later.

Comment: I am essentially using this open source checkbox tree:
https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree/tree/master/src/js

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your component CheckboxTree does, but here is some info that applies to regular input controls:

Your event handler onChecked is expecting checked to be the value of your checkbox, but in fact it will be an event object. So you need to get the value from the event object and set the state with that:

```
  onCheck(e) {
    console.log(e);
    let checked = {checked: e.target.value}
    this.setState({
      checked,
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I see from the documentation that they are doing it the same way, so it should work, because your code is equivalent to this:

```
  onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}
  onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
```

Comment: when I make that change, I get a console error that says it cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

Comment: I am using react-checkbox-tree if that helps any, I assume I would have to make changes to the source code there in order to pull something like this off, but again, I am new to react and I am not quite sure.

Comment: hmm okay, I tried it again and got the same console error, I have changed the `onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}` in my code to what you have above: ```onCheck(e) {
    console.log(e);
    let checked = {checked: e.target.value}
    this.setState({
      checked,
    });
  }```

Am I missing something?